# Optimality condition of the harmonic form representatives of a homology class

Tags: cohomology, hodge-theory, homology, laplacian

In ["Hodge theory on metric spaces, Smale et al."](https://home.ttic.edu/%7Esmale/papers/hodge_theory_on_metric_spaces.pdf) the $d$-th harmonic forms of the Hodge Laplacian $\Delta_d=\delta^* \delta+\delta \delta^*$ satisfying $\Delta_d(f)=0$ are claimed to be special representatives of their homology class, interpreted as satisfying an *optimality condition*.

Which is this optimality condition?

Comment: I believe this is just semantics; they're saying "optimal form = harmonic form" relative to all others that represent a fixed class (the condition = solving Hodge-Laplace equation).

Comment: Harmonic forms on compact manifolds minimize L^2-norm $\int\alpha \wedge \star \alpha$ in their homology class